# Why isn't jQuery .text() method working to grab text from a td

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to grab the email address from a number of different emails, and am trying to use a jQuery selector to grab those. However, I keep getting the message `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

The html appears as follows:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>Activate Your Groupon Account</title>
      <link rel="important stylesheet" href="">
      <style>div.headerdisplayname {font-weight:bold;}</style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part1">
         <tbody></tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">Subject: </div>
               Activate Your Groupon Account
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">From: </div>
               Groupon <notify@r.groupon.com>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">Date: </div>
               10/8/2014 12:25 PM
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part2">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">To: </div>
               myEmail@gmail.com
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <br>
      <div class="moz-text-html"  lang="x-unicode">
         <html>
            <head>
               <title>Groupon | Wednesday, October 8, 2014</title>
               <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; ">
            </head>
            <body style="height:100%; margin:0!important; padding:0!important;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; background:#89B556;">
               <img src = "http://www.groupon.com/analytic/track.gif?p=1&utm_domain=gmail.com&utm_campaign=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&utm_source=activation_notification&utm_medium=email&sid=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&user=fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106&date=20141008" height="1" width="1" />    
               <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333; width:100%; background:#89B556;" bgcolor="#89B556" valign="top" align="center">
                  <tr>
                     <td style="width:33%;" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                     <td style="width:33%; padding: 0 25px 40px 25px;" valign="top" align="center">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333;" width="600" align="center">
                           <tr>
                              <td style="padding: 0 0 0 10px;" align="left" valign="bottom">
                                 <a href="http://www.groupon.com/?utm_source=activation_notification&utm_medium=email&sid=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&user=fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106&date=20141008&s=header&c=logo&d=index&utm_campaign=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da"><img src="http://s3.grouponcdn.com/email/images/global_images/logo_pg_top.png" style="display: block; border: none; color:#fff; font-size:22px; font-weight:bold;" alt="GROUPON" title="GROUPON"></a>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td style="-moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; -khtml-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; background:#fff; padding: 0 0 0 10px;" align="left" valign="top"><a href="http://www.groupon.com/?utm_source=activation_notification&utm_medium=email&sid=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&user=fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106&date=20141008&s=header&c=logo&d=index&utm_campaign=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da"><img src="http://s3.grouponcdn.com/email/images/global_images/logo_pg_bottom.gif" style="display: block; border: none; color:#fff; font-size:22px; font-weight:bold;" alt="" title=""></a></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td style="background:#fff;">
                                 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333; width:100%;" align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>
                                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333;">
                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="padding:0 18px 20px 25px;">
                                                   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333; width:540px;text-align: left; line-height:18px; font-weight: 100;" width="540">
                                                      <tr>
                                                         <td style="font-size: 22px; color:#82b548; padding: 20px 0 30px 0; font-weight: bold; line-height:28px;">Thanks for Joining!</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr>
                                                         <td style="font-family:arial; font-size:20px; color:#949494; line-height: 26px;">You’re going to love it</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr>
                                                         <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cfe1bc; font-size: 14px; padding: 20px 40px 20px 0;">Check your inbox every day to discover Groupon deals with huge discounts on tasty meals, relaxing spa days, concerts, 5-star hotels and more.</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr>
                                                         <td style="padding: 30px 0 10px 0;">To complete your registration for Groupon, please verify your email.</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr>
                                                         <td style="padding: 10px 0 20px 0;">
                                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333;'>
                                                               <tr>
                                                                  <td height="40" width="185" bgcolor="#f98b62" background="http://s3.grouponcdn.com/email/images/global_buttons/gradient_orange_sm.gif" background-repeat="repeat-x" style="height: 40px; -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px; border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px; -khtml-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px; border: 1px solid #f55d16; text-align: center;">
                                                                     <a href="https://www.groupon.com/users/activate/8eceddecb9f30c3384fb2507b0d234805698010c?utm_source=activation_notification&utm_medium=email&sid=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&user=fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106&date=20141008&s=secondary-content-area&c=button&d=verify-account&utm_campaign=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da" style="padding:5px 20px 5px 20px; color: #fff; text-shadow:  1px 1px 1px #b2552d; font-size: 18px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; display: block;" target="_blank" title="Verify Account">Verify Account</a>
                                                                  </td>
                                                               </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                         </td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                   </table>
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </table>
                                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333; border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; text-align:left;">
                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px;">
                                                   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333;">
                                                      <tr>
                                                         <td><a href="https://www.groupon.com/myprofile?utm_source=activation_notification&utm_medium=email&sid=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&user=fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106&date=20141008&s=secondary-content-area&c=image&d=personalize&utm_campaign=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da" style="color:#0185C6; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://s3.grouponcdn.com/email/images/welcome-email/personalize.gif" style="display: block; border: none;" alt="Personalize your deals" title="Personalize your deals"></a></td>
                                                         <td style="padding: 0 0 0 20px;">
                                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333; font-weight: 100; text-align: left;">
                                                               <tr>
                                                                  <td><a href="https://www.groupon.com/myprofile?utm_source=activation_notification&utm_medium=email&sid=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&user=fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106&date=20141008&s=secondary-content-area&c=text-link&d=personalize&utm_campaign=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da" style="color:#0185C6; text-decoration:none; font-weight: bold;">Personalize your deals</a></td>
                                                               </tr>
                                                               <tr>
                                                                  <td style="padding: 5px 0 0 0;">Help us get you the best deals by completing your profile.</td>
                                                               </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                         </td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                   </table>
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </table>
                                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333; border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; text-align: left;">
                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px;">
                                                   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333; text-align:left;">
                                                      <tr>
                                                         <td><a href="http://www.groupon.com/groupon-promise?utm_source=activation_notification&utm_medium=email&sid=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&user=fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106&date=20141008&s=secondary-content-area&c=image&d=groupon-promise&utm_campaign=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da" style="color:#0185C6; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://s3.grouponcdn.com/email/images/welcome-email/promise.gif" style="display: block; border: none;" alt="We got your back" title="We got your back"></a></td>
                                                         <td>
                                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333; font-weight: bold; color: #5f8237;">
                                                               <tr>
                                                                  <td>The</td>
                                                               </tr>
                                                               <tr>
                                                                  <td>GROUPON</td>
                                                               </tr>
                                                               <tr>
                                                                  <td style="padding: 0 30px 25px 0;">Promise</td>
                                                               </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                         </td>
                                                         <td style="padding: 0 0 0 20px;">
                                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333; font-weight:100; text-align:left;">
                                                               <tr>
                                                                  <td><a href="http://www.groupon.com/groupon-promise?utm_source=activation_notification&utm_medium=email&sid=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&user=fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106&date=20141008&s=secondary-content-area&c=text-link&d=groupon-promise&utm_campaign=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da" style="color:#0185C6; text-decoration:none; font-weight: bold;">We got your back</a></td>
                                                               </tr>
                                                               <tr>
                                                                  <td style="padding: 5px 0 5px 0;">If the experience using your Groupon ever lets you down, we’ll make it right or return your purchase.</td>
                                                               </tr>
                                                               <tr>
                                                                  <td>Simple as that.</td>
                                                               </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                         </td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                   </table>
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333; width:600px; border-top: 1px solid #7a9e32; text-align: center; " width="600" background="#ddeacf" bgcolor="#ddeacf" align="center">
                           <tr>
                              <td style="padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px; color:#666; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;" align="center">
                                 Need help? <span style="color:#0185C6; text-decoration:none;"><a href="https://www.groupon.com/helpcenter?utm_source=activation_notification&utm_medium=email&sid=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&user=fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106&date=20141008&s=contact-block&c=text-link&d=contact-groupon&utm_campaign=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da" style="color:#0185C6; text-decoration:none;">Contact Groupon</a></span>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:19px; color:#333; background:#eff5e7; width:600px; -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;" align="center" width="600">
                           <tr>
                              <td style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0; font-size: 10px; text-align: center;">Delivered by Groupon Inc. 600 W. Chicago Avenue, Suite 400 Chicago, IL, 60654, USA</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td style="padding: 0 20px 0 20px; font-size:10px; line-height: 14px; color:#666666; text-align: left;" valign="top">
                                 You are receiving this email because you signed up for the Daily Groupon alerts. If you prefer not to receive the daily Groupon email, you can always <a href="https://www.groupon.com/subscription_center/fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106?mobile=false&utm_source=activation_notification&utm_medium=email&sid=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&user=fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106&date=20141008&s=footer&c=link&d=subs-center&utm_campaign=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da" style="color:#0185C6; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">manage your subscriptions</a>. Be sure to add us to your address book or safe sender list so our emails get to your inbox. <a href="http://www.groupon.com/pages/whitelist?utm_source=activation_notification&utm_medium=email&sid=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&user=fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106&date=20141008&s=footer&c=link&d=groupon_whitelist&utm_campaign=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da" style="color:#0185C6; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">Learn how</a>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 20px 0;"><a href="http://www.groupon.com?utm_source=activation_notification&utm_medium=email&sid=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&user=fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106&date=20141008&s=footer&c=logo&d=index&utm_campaign=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da"><img src="http://s3.grouponcdn.com/email/images/global_images/footer_pg_ico.gif" style="display: block; border: none;" alt="GROUPON" title="GROUPON"></a></td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width:33%;" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
               <img src = "http://www.groupon.com/analytic/track.gif?p=2&utm_domain=gmail.com&utm_campaign=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&utm_source=activation_notification&utm_medium=email&sid=55dd4215-7b6d-4818-9a72-0da61a4540da&user=fb4de52d8d1af92fd57e6e895aa7c9a0f846d88bd27c203571f4e3776baa6106&date=20141008" height="1" width="1" />  
            </body>
         </html>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
</table></div>
```

The code I am using to select this works:

```
$('tr:nth-child(2) td')
```

But as soon as I try and grab the text it breaks:

```
$('tr:nth-child(2) td').text()
```

Comment: Can you show the parent elements as well?

Comment: Looks like your email information is being interpreted as html tags. Not sure how this data is being generated, but your less than and greater symbols, denoting opening and closing tags, should be encoded as &lt; and &gt;

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery loaded properly?

Comment: Have you tried to see if html() works?

Comment: The error message implies that `$('tr:nth-child(2) td')` is not returning a jQuery object.

Comment: But it says in the question that the selection code is working...

Comment: @Barmar when I just run $('tr:nth-child(2) td') it returns the jQuery object

Comment: Would it matter if I were running this code in the browser?

Comment: That's the normal place to run Javascript.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: If that is all the parent elements, then `<tbody>` has to be a child of `<table>` or the jQuery selector will ignore the entire thing as invalid HTML.

Comment: @MagnusEngdal Is correct. Here's the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/h58hvxxk/ - You have to make the HTML elements valid before jQuery can play nice with them.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u6oa25b5/

Comment: @Steven `$('tr:nth-child(2) td').html()` does not work...returns `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: What do you see if you enter `$.fn` into your JavaScript console? How about `$.fn.text` ? If they're both undefined, you're not using jQuery and have a selector shim that uses `$` like jQuery.

Comment: @maudulus, Please read magnus' comment here.  If he doesn't write it as an answer, I will

Comment: @maudulus everybody wants to see the code with html, not just html. As it was said before - it looks like you are not loading jQuery library or you have a conflict with another javascript framework, for example with `mootools`

Comment: @Cheery what do you mean by  `everybody wants to see the code with html, not just html.`

Comment: Tried removing `<` and `>` from around `<notify@r.groupon.com>` http://jsfiddle.net/7on58hdt/ , as pointed out by @EvilJordan ? Not certain of reason for those characters ?, though they could be rendered via css , if required ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the other answers worked for this, which is likely due to something with jQuery on this page. The `$` selector worked, but typing in `jQuery` was undefined.

This was what worked in the end:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.headerdisplayname')[1].parentNode.children[1].tagName
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr > td')[1].children[1].tagName
```

Comment: `but typing in jQuery was undefined` it meant what I told you - you do not have jQuery loaded, but have something like `mootools` on the page (it also uses `$` symbol)! And was repeated several times. If you would say that you do not want to use jQuery then the answer will be on pure javascript. And if you showed the full code of the page from the beginning - there will be not so many comments and discussions.

Answer (score 0):

REVISED ANSWER DUE TO NEW REQUIREMENTS:

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2uvk9zxp/ 
Assuming the email you want is in the exact same place every time, you will have to grab certain elements and split it in certain places.

Here's the javascript I was using:

```
var getEmail = $('tr:nth-of-type(2) td').html().split("Groupon ")[1].split(" ")[0].replace("<","").replace(">","");
console.log(getEmail);
```

END REVISED

The problem is that your `<tbody>` is not contained inside of a `<table>` As Magnus Engdal said, it is invalid markup and therefor is not read properly by the javascript.

All you have to do is wrap your table in actual `<table></table` tags.

Here's a fiddle of the example WITHOUT table tags:
http://jsfiddle.net/h58hvxxk/2/

And here is an example WITH table tags:
http://jsfiddle.net/h58hvxxk/3/

You can see the alert box is working properly, pulling the text you are looking for. - This credit goes towards Magnus, so if he writes this same answer, you need to accept and vote up his. - P.S. Don't let the fact that I wrote a `(1)` instead of `(2)` deter you from seeing it works just fine.

Comment: The problem is not related to table structure. Even if the structure is wrong, there will be no such error message.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/u6oa25b5

Comment: @Cheery, With the code that was given, it works just fine when I added the table tags.  With the new code and the fiddle that was just provided, it works perfectly fine as well.  I see no issues except the fact that there's no full javascript shown.  He's only showing how he's selecting - but we don't know if he's even allowed it to fire.

Comment: is there a way I can grab this email without using the tbody tags, since I am not the author of this formatting?

Comment: @maudulus you are not required to use `tbody` tags, do not listen him. And everything is fine with your table. The problem is not related to that.

Comment: @maudulus, You are trying to get the groupon email? or the myemail@gmail.com?

Comment: @maudulus I'll submit it in the answer here in a second

Comment: @Cheery, When the question was first asked, he didn't mention any of that.  But you are incorrect if you're saying I'm wrong that you have to WRAP A TABLE IN TABLE TAGS for it to be valid.  jQuery WILL NOT RECOGNIZE what you want if there are no table tags - Look at this fiddle and see for yourself http://jsfiddle.net/2uvk9zxp/1/

Comment: @ntgCleaner I do not see any problem with the table neither in the question, nor in the links provided to jsfiddle. Even if it does not recognize the structure - !it will not create this error message!, it is so obvious.

Comment: @cheery, You're correct about the error message.  When I first answered the question, that message was not provided. Though it DOES matter that the table structure is correct.  Go to my fiddle example and read the console.  It will read as blank or undefined when you remove the table tags

Comment: @ntgCleaner I know that if you do not have `table` tags you will not work with `tr` and `td`, read carefully my comments - `tbody` is not required, a was never talking about `table` tag.

Comment: @cheery why did you even start to bring up tbody?  no one said the tbody was wrong or even necessary.  Who brought that up? I never said tbody tags were necessary. I said it's necessary for the tbody tags to be contained in a table tag

Comment: @Cheery, Also it was unclear when I was answering the question that the email he's skimming from is not his own.  It's still unclear when you read the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm tied of all the comments that are not read by TS.

1. There is no problem with your table structure.
2. The error `TypeError: undefined is not a function` tells that
   either your jQuery is not             loaded and js knows nothing
   about `$()` structure or you have a conflict on the page with
   another js framework (like `mootools`). In order to resolve this
   conflict - use `jQuery('tr:nth-child(2) td').text()`
3. Show you full code of the page with js code, not just a portion of it.
4. `<notify@r.groupon.com>` is not accessible through the `.text()` function **as browser thinks that this is a tag**. Use `.html()` and parse. Look here - http://jsfiddle.net/u6oa25b5/1/
5. It is possible to do so without parsing the html code.

Like this (email here is inside of a `div` tag, just for simplicity) - http://jsfiddle.net/u6oa25b5/2/

```
var email = $('div').find('*').filter(function(){
  if (this.tagName.search(/@/) !== -1)
      return this;
});

alert(email[0].tagName);
```

Comment: Just curious , meaning of "TS" ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 TS = topic starter

Answer (score 0):

Try

html

```
      <td>
         <div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">From: </div>
          <!-- wrap email address inside `span` tag -->
          Groupon <span>notify@r.groupon.com</span>
      </td>
```

js

```
// apply rendering of `<` , `>` around email address text in `span`
var email = $("tr:nth-child(2) td span").before("<").after(">").text();
console.log(email)
```

to replace literal `<` , `>` , at `html`. If email address is to render as actual navigatable *link* ? , wrap instead in `a` (anchor) tag , then set the `a` tag's `href` attribute to `mailto:notify@r.groupon.com`

```js
var email = $("tr:nth-child(2) td span").before("<").after(">").css("color", "blue").text();
console.log(email)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part1">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">Subject: </div>
         Activate Your Groupon Account
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">From: </div>
          Groupon <span>notify@r.groupon.com</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">Date: </div>
         10/8/2014 12:25 PM
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part2">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">To: </div>
         myEmail@gmail.com
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```